# Shortcut web page file in PHP

Tags: php, file, shortcut

I wish I knew how to make a file that is a principal access to a web page. I'm using PHP to do this. It occurred to me the following:

```
function crearArchivoUrl($url){
        $archivo=str_replace(array("http://", "https://", "mailto://", "ftp://"), "", $url);
        $archivo=str_replace(array("/"), "-", $archivo);
        $this->checkNombreDestino($archivo);
        $contenido="[InternetShortcut]\r\nURL=".$url."\r\n";
        $fp = fopen($archivo, 'w');
        chmod($archivo, 0644);
        fwrite($fp, $contenido);
        fclose($fp);
    }
```

But when I test it (by double-clicking on it) I did not jump the browser.

Anybody can tell me how to make files that are shortcuts to web pages?

Thanks for the help.

Greetings!

Comment: Could you explain what you are wanting to do with a bit more detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My code was correct, all I needed was that the file extension should be .url, ie, my-web-shortcut.url

Thanks for everything.

Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP will only be executed if you have a PHP interpreter installed, and if the webserver is configured to run your PHP file. If you distribute this file to unconfigured computers, it will never be executed as PHP code, and will therefore never run as you expect.

If you are running this script on a webserver that is properly configured, consider using `header("Location: <URL>")` to redirect the user to the new page.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you are reading a file, and writing it to another file. Doing that sends nothing to the web browser.

A first approach would be to send a [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) Location to redirect the broswer. See examples in the manual to know how to use it.

Another approach would be to read the file contents, and to print it, using [echo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) or any other printing command.